# Username/ Password. SignUp and Connection View

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my problem :

I have two pages :
1) 'Connection page' where the user has to write his username and password.  This view is a ViewController class.
If the user doesn't have a password and an username : he can push a button with a link forward a new page called 'Sign Up page'

2) 'SignUp page' : on this page the user creates a new account : i ask him an username, a password with confirmation, and the same thing with his email address.
This page is a ViewControllerSign class, subclass of Viewcontroller class.

I tried to use a dictionary to save the new username and the password but i think it's not a good solution (it worked but i could only create 1 account each time i ran the app in the simulator : if i wanted created a new account, the last account was deleted) because i would like save the new account created forever.
I read a lot of topics with NSUserDefaults and it seems being the best way but i admit it's little difficult for me actually...

This is the part of my code for trying to save the new username and password created in the ViewControllerSign.m

```
NSString *savedata = usernameRegistration.text;   // textField username signUp page
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:savedata forKey:passwordRegistration1.text];
[defaults synchronize];
```

I don't know if this code saves anything...

And next, when the account is created, the user returns automatically ( it's already done) on the 'Connection Page' to use his username and password just created and continue to enjoy my great app :)

How i can do to transfer the data saved in the signUp page to the Connection Page  and use them to perform the recognition Username - Password ( and get the possibility to create more than one account) ?

Thank you in advance !

If i forgot anything and you need more information, np :)

Comment: Usually, account creation is handled by a web service. If the account is stored locally, the user can't log in from another device, and their account will be lost forever if the app is deleted.

Comment: Thanks for your response !
I forgot some precisions :), i just want a local account, not need to use a web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know what you are trying to do, but if you want not to lose previously entered information, keep them in a mutable array:

```
#define kUD_Users @"UD_Users"
NSMutableArray* users = [NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults objectForKey:kUD_Users];
if(!users) users = NSMutableArray.array;

[users addObject:@{@"username": txt_username.text, @"password": txt_password.text}];

[NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults setObject:users forKey:kUD_Users];
[NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults synchronize];
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSUserDefaults` is good for quick preference items, but for a user database, you probably want to use an SQLite database (which you can do in iOS using [sqlite3](http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-making-our-app)).

A how-to guide on SQLite is outside the scope of stack overflow, so I included the link above.